# Visual Studio "go to header file" not working with hpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

The very handy right click menu option "Go To Header File" in Visual Studio 2005 doesn't seem to work if my header file is an .hpp file for that module; I've deleted/rebuilt the intellisense file but it still doesn't want to know.
Is there a setting or something somewhere to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does your project filter for the headers folder include hpp?

You can check by right clicking on the Header Files folder going to properties and it should have something like h;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd defined in the Filter property.

This can sometimes be a quirky feature of Visual Studio I've found since upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 that it takes and inordinately longer amount of time to use goto definition or goto declaration to the point where I've completely stopped using it in favor of just searching the project or solution and picking it out from the output window instead.